# What is the link between the LESS language and the Less framework?

Tags: css, less, css-frameworks

I'm looking into using the Less framework to build a new website, but I'm curious about one point. Is it related to the LESS stylesheet language ? Does Less even uses LESS to build its CSS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the [Less framework](http://lessframework.com) and the [LESS language](http://lesscss.org) are completely unrelated. Contrary to what you say, the framework doesn't even appear to utilize any language features of LESS — its stylesheet seems to be written purely in standard CSS. You can see it in the source preview in the [Getting Started](http://lessframework.com/#get) section.

Comment: I thought I had read that Less uses LESS. You're right that doesn't seem to be the case.